# Where can I download 'Daylight Saving Time' for all regions in the world for specific year?

Tags: data-request

Where can I download 'Daylight Saving Time' for all regions in the world for specific year like 2015?

timeanddate.com provides it but it's not free.

This is a sample data provided by timeanddate.com

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data version="2">
  <dstlist>
    <dstentry>
      <region>
        <country id="al">Republic of Albania</country>
        <desc>All locations</desc>
        <biggestplace>Tirana</biggestplace>
        <locations>
          <location id="284" name="Tirana"/>
        </locations>
      </region>
      <stdtimezone offset="+01:00">
        <zoneabb>CET</zoneabb>
        <zonename>Central European Time</zonename>
        <zoneoffset>3600</zoneoffset>
        <zonedst>0</zonedst>
        <zonetotaloffset>3600</zonetotaloffset>
      </stdtimezone>
      <dsttimezone offset="+02:00">
        <zoneabb>CEST</zoneabb>
        <zonename>Central European Summer Time</zonename>
        <zoneoffset>3600</zoneoffset>
        <zonedst>3600</zonedst>
        <zonetotaloffset>7200</zonetotaloffset>
      </dsttimezone>
      <dststart>2011-03-27</dststart>
      <dstend>2011-10-30</dstend>
    </dstentry>
  </dstlist>
</data>
```

As you can see, we have

```
  <dststart>2011-03-27</dststart>
  <dstend>2011-10-30</dstend>
```

Which shows start and end time of daylight saving for 2011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](http://www.iana.org/) maintains a database of time zones. For countries/localities that have daylight savings, they have documented the rules.

The database is here: http://www.iana.org/time-zones

IATA's TZ coordinator also has a github repository with this information: https://github.com/eggert/tz

Comment: Does it provide the start and end time DST every year? I think not.

Comment: @sqluser : as your example was 'such as 2015', this would answer your question.  If you want historical info, this only goes back a couple of years ... but you could look for 'tzdata' or 'zoneinfo' files from old unix distributions from the year you're interested in.

Comment: @sqluser if you need it for many years you might want to specify that in the documentation. Also, according to their documentation, TZ has historical information - if it exists - for all countries since ~ 1970.

Comment: Thanks @RebeccaAckermana and Joe. After investigating more on it, found that it provides all timezones and related DST rules for all globe regions even for historical data.

Answer (score 2):

WebExhibits has a Daylight Savings Time exhibit which has this data:
http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/g.html

Comment: Thanks but it has limited regions and also just defines the start and end time of daylight saving by saying something like last Friday of Sep. It's not accurate.

Comment: what would be an appropriate state/end? you should add these details to your question

Comment: Updated the question @albert

Comment: "last friday of september" is accurate enough, if you want to specify a year, a simple php command like `date('Ymd', strtotime("last friday of september 2015"));` gives the precise date.

Comment: Unfortunatly is not as easy as this. Some countries change their dts regulary. Possibly first Friday of Sep in 2015 can be changed to first Saturday of Sep in 2016.